# UnicodeDecodeError on sockets.gethostbyaddr

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to run simple `hello world` **flask** **app** but sockets throws an error on Windows 10.

```
File "D:\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn:
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 80: invalid start byte
```

I know I could hack some code in the source of socket.py but I don't want to do that yet. My hostname is "Pitku" so I don't know what text/character is causing the error.

Is there any way to backtrace/fix this error?

Comment: can you post the content of the `name` variable here?

Comment: @Joost 127.0.0.1

Comment: Which python version? There was a change 3.5 ish to stop using unicode on Windows. https://bugs.python.org/issue26227. This is in the C socket implementation so a `socket.py` hack is not enough.

Comment: In later code I see `PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault` which I guess is using `sys.getfilesystemdefault()` value for the socket. The 0xab byte is no good in ascii either so maybe this is some code page thing?

Comment: @tdelaney Python 3.6.4, have tried multiple Code Pages but none worked